# Using windows instead of views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Just curious to know, (well i know its bad) but why its bad i dont know?

Instead of using many views, why cant we just use windows instead? Are there any disadvantage?

Comment: Well, a `UIWindow` is just a subclass of a `UIView`, so I really don't  see any reason not to, but I also don't see any particular reason to use windows instead of views

Answer (score 2):

A `UIWindow` is what contains the root view controller. By using a `UIWindow` instead of a `UIView`, you'll mess up that whole hierarchy. It would go from `UIWindow -> UIViewController -> UIView` to just `UIWindow` or maybe `UIWindow -> UIViewController -> UIWindow`? Also keep in mind that a view controller can manage more than one view, and a view can have any number of subviews. For this reason, there is usually only one root view controller which can then pass control to other view controllers as need be. If you were using `UIWindow` in place of `UIView` you would have a lot of root view controllers... hopefully you can see why that is bad.

Comment: What about two windows in one app? When User logged in, user logged out. Both separate wndows

Comment: Logged in window manages logged in features, while logged out window is probably just the login and registration form? Maybe a tutorial screen aswell.

Comment: I've used UIWindow without UIView on a few, rare occasions, but only when I know I'm only going to have one view in my app (and therefore no need for a navigation controller), and only when I can live without a UIViewController. Those situations are few and far between. It's a shortcut, for sure, not a recommended practice. Better to stick to the view heirarchy as @John Corbett described it, even when you only need one view.

Comment: @001 I would have different view controllers to do those things. There is hardly ever a reason to have more than 1 window.

Answer (score 0):

Per proper software interface design, utilizing multiple windows will break a user's "flow", making the software less efficient and less enjoyable for the user. Although designing software will multiple windows is doable, it is widely considered bad practice.

Utilizing multiple views, along with things such as tab views and transitions, makes an application much more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

As above said using views increment usage experience for users of your software, but there are applications where you need to use windows, e.g. iCall where each chat session is in separate chat window.

Edit: Hmm... seen just now that your question is about iPhone, in this case you can use same view for different chat sessions. This is because on iPhone you generally have no space to see more that one...